# Cannot seem to access S3 bucket contents with key

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I am using the aws javascript sdk and for some reason I can access the entire buckets contents, but when I add a `prefix` I get `null` returned rather than a subset of those contents.  For example, the following returns all bucket contents:

```
AWS.config.accessKeyId = this.s3.config["accessKeyId"];
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = this.s3.config["secretAccessKey"];
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-2';

var aws = new AWS.S3();
var all_params = {Bucket: 'bucket-name'};

new Promise(resolve => {
  aws.listObjectsV2(all_params, function (err, url) {
    console.log(url)
    resolve(url)
  });
})
```

The object returned contains 1000 records, most of them in the format `Key: "clients/after_fronts/000..."`.  However when I run the following, I get a `null` object:

```
AWS.config.accessKeyId = this.s3.config["accessKeyId"];
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = this.s3.config["secretAccessKey"];
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-2';

var key = "clients"
var aws = new AWS.S3();
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket-name', prefix: key};

return new Promise(resolve => {
  aws.listObjectsV2(params, function (err, url) {
    console.log(url)
    resolve(url)
  });
})
```

I thought it might be a permissions issue but I'm not sure why it returns data without a prefix and then no data with the prefix.  What else could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after staring at this for an hour I realized the docs call for `Prefix` not `prefix` and that capitalization made all the difference.